# BackboneJS rendering views within views

Tags: json, backbone.js, recursion, view, nested

I am having trouble getting my head around something that to me ought to be really really basic. I am sure that all I need is a single line answer that hopefully will make everything worthwhile! :) Before anyone asks, yes I have spent over 48 hours trying to figure it out, reading countless articles but nothing seems to really hit the nail on the head and so I really appreciate the help.

What I am trying to build is a relatively simple decision tree diagram, where any node will not have more than two possible outcomes.

My initial idea is simple: I have a template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="answer-template">
   <section class="outerbox">
        <article class="first_line" id="first_line_<%- id %>">
            <label><%- text %></label>
        </article>
        <article class="second_line" id="second_line_<%- id %>">
            <div class="second_line_left" id="second_line_left_<%- id %>">
                <!-- append this for no answer //-->
            </div>
            <div class="second_line_right" id="second_line_right_<%- id %>">
                <!-- append this for yes answer //-->
            </div>
        </article>
   </section>
</script>
```

and as simply put as possible, what I want is this template to be recursively appending itself in the secoond_line_left and second_line_right div boxes.

The type of JSON that I will be receiving will be the form of:

```
{ "id": 1, 
  "question": "Do you like JavaScript", 
  "yes":{
          "id":2, 
          "question": "Have you tried JQuery", 
          "yes": {...}, 
          "no":{...}
  }, 
  "no":{
          "id":5, 
          "question": "Have you tried JavaScript", 
          "yes": {...}, 
          "no":{...}
  }
}
```

where the {...} denotes that the same type of format would occur.

So what I am trying to do in the views is as follows:

```
 add_one: function(answer) {
        var view = new AnswerView({model: answer});
        $("#"+this.options.append_this).append(view.render().el);

        if(answer.attributes.yes){
          var so_yes = "second_line_right_"+answer.attributes.id;
         // here i want to call the add_one function again to append to the element
         // with id seen in the so_yes variable above, and the json inside the "yes"
         // key of the JSON currently being recursively executed
        }

        if(answer.attributes.no){
         var so_no = "second_line_left_"+answer.attributes.id;
         // here i want to call the add_one function again to append to the element
         // with id seen in the so_no variable above, and the json inside the "no"
         // key of the JSON currently being recursively executed
        }

    },
```

I have tried to call the function from within itself in quite a few different ways, passing in the JSON and the ID of the elements... I have tried to re-render the view everytime I get to a yes or a no, but I can't seem to be able to so...

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I assume it must be a really simple one line answer? Am I wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Backbone doesn't seem like a good fit for this. The fact that you're dealing with a deeply nested JSON and then trying to create a model and view for each node. Why not just try to do it with jQuery and templates?

Comment: Yeah... when I realised that no-one had responded to the task I set out to re-write it all as native javascript and jquery. Backbone is great for most things but clearly not this type of work! Shame really because it limits the amount of data manipulation that you could do! but anyway..! THANK YOU